# Change Screen/Monitor name in xorg.conf from DFP to HDMI

Tags: 14.04, gnome, xrandr, amd-graphics, xorg.conf

I want to know if it is possible to change the name that xorg has given my TV from DFP5 back to HDMI-0? It changed with the AMD proprietary drivers installation. With it being HDMI-0 I could set `xrander underscan on` and adjust `underscan hborder` and `underscan vborder` so that the disaply fits in my TV. Now that it is detected as DFP, xrandr does not recognize the underscan option. Please? and thank you...

SPECS:

- Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.4
- AMD GPU R9 270
- TELEFUNKEN 26" Model: TLED-26FHDP

Comment: You shouldn't need to use xrandr. It's a common mistake. Users assume something must be tweaked at the OS when actually they should adjust it in the TV. TVs by default overscan to compensate for the cable set-top boxes but any TV, either at the settings menu or just a key in the remote, has a function to adjust for full rather than underscanned video inputs. Do not ask how, that's you homework: Read the manual and/or ask the tech support / customer service of you TV's brand.

Comment: Dear CelticWarrior, thank you for the recommendation, but believe me if I tell you that it is not the case for all TV's. One of those cases is me, with my Telefunken that I've had for 5 years now. I have tried everything else but in the end I always had to go change the scaling options in the ATI Catalyst Control Center. That was in all the windows OS's I had before. Now I have moved to Linux(3 days), and I cannot for the life of me get the scaling options in the ATI CCC to let me in. They are disabled for some reason. Have not found a solution for that anywhere.

Comment: I always without believe until I see evidence. What is the TV's model? It's advisable to edit your question and add that info as well.

Comment: Does your remote look like this? -> https://www.manualslib.com/manual/665389/Telefunken-Tf-Led19s2.html?page=7#manual    <- Use key #3. One of the modes will fit.